# Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type array

Tags: angular

```
 getLanguageList()
  {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:51601/api/LanguageTables')
    .map((data : Response) =>{
      return data.json() as Language[];

    }).toPromise().then(x =>{
      this.languageList=x;
    })
  }
```

I have created a interface which contains my database fields.secondly i have created a service in which i have created a function to access the data using Http services.Now i want to display the data in the mat-table using the same created function.

Comment: Check that `data` which comes from the server contains anything.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to actually return the language list, in this example you are returning nothing.

Log out each of your variables along the way and see if they are what you expect.